# How to retrieve elements in a column that is a list type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where one of the columns is a list.
For example:

```
name   fruits                       age
Ash   ['banana', 'kiwi']             12
Ray   ['orange', 'kiwi', 'apple']    14
```

I would like to get the unique elements in fruits and pivot.

```
name  age   banana    kiwi    orange   apple   
Ash    12      1       1        0        0      
Ray    14      0       1        1        1
```

Comment: Shouldn't `kiwi` be a `1` for `Ash`?

Comment: this is not a pivot, use `get_dummies`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes you are right. editted!

Comment: `out = df.drop(columns=['fruits']).join(df['fruits'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies())`